# Formatting C# code in VSCode doesn't look right

Tags: c#, visual-studio-code

I haven't written any C# code for quite a while and would like to get back to it. I set up .NET SDK and VSCode + C# extension pack and am trying to get it to work. Everything runs smoothly but I'm very confused about the formatting. Whenever I try to format code in VSCode, it only does "basic" things and doesn't touch very long lines or function arguments passed on different lines that don't really look right. Anything I could do to do more "strict" formatting?

E.g. this code doesn't get modified by the formatter at all:

```cs
// This is a very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very long line
void Foo(double x, double y)
{
}

Foo(1,
          2);

var y = 42; var z = 1;
```

I also made sure I have Csharp > Format: Enable set to true in my VSCode settings and I do get messages from the Language Server (e.g. I can navigate the code, use Go To to jump to functions in Standard Library and in my code etc).

I installed .NET SDK, VSCode, verified that it works, created a new project through `dotnet new console`, created a sample file and ran formatter on some code. When I run formatting on the following code

```cs
// This is a very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very long line
void Foo(double x, double y)
{
}

Foo(1,
          2);

var y = 42; var z = 1;
```

I would expect it to at least format the last few lines as

```cs
Foo(1, 2);
// or
Foo(1,
    2);

var y = 42;
var z = 1;
```

But it seems to not modify this code at all. Also, I've tried looking through the VSCode settings but found no luck.

I also have a `test.csproj` file in my project.

Comment: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=csharpier.csharpier-vscode

Comment: @stuartd I've seen this one, but does the official extension really not provide enough formatting that one has to opt for a third-party formatter?

Answer (score 0):

I guess the issue is that OmniSharp's formatting is pretty basic, so I had to install CSharpier as @stuartd suggested.

Comment: If you're going to answer your own question, please make sure to add all the relevant details from all comments that have helped and include any links that may have been commented. This helps greatly for future Googlers, so they get straight to the answer instead of trying to find the comment that you mention.